# How to adjust pom.xml to access jar in same package but different build directory?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, classloader, pom.xml

I have a Java project with two separate components that build to two separate .jar files, one of which is an agent and the other of which is a runtime.

I am trying to get the agent (`Agent.java`) to run the `main()` method of `LangagentApplication.java` in the runtime by first using `ClassLoader.getResource()` to access the .jar file containing LangagentApplication, but I am having trouble actually accessing the runtime .jar file. I am currently using the following: `getResource("target/runtime.jar")`, which is simply returning `null`. When printing the class path, the runtime .jar is not included.

Please refer to directory structure below.

```
project
--pom.xml
--agent
  --src
    --main/java/.../Agent.java
  --target
    --agent.jar
    --...
  --pom.xml
--runtime
  --src
    --main/java/.../LangagentApplication.java
  --target
    --runtime.jar
    --...
  --pom.xml
```

Notes:
- I am referring to the jar files as `agent.jar` and `runtime.jar` for simplicity - their actual names are much longer and messier.
- Both agent and runtime use the same package (`com.spnlangagent.langagent`)
- Java 1.8

I am running Maven and Java as follows (from the project directory):

```
mvn package
java -cp /path/to/project/runtime/target/runtime.jar -javaagent:/path/to/project/agent/target/agent.jar -jar otherjar.jar
```

I am currently doing the following code-wise:

```
private static void startRuntime(String agentArgs) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("startRuntime: now running with agentArgs: " + agentArgs);
    //Create a temporary file for the jar
    File output = File.createTempFile("runtime", "jar");
    //Attempt to load the runtime jar
    try (InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("target/runtime.jar").openStream()) {
        Files.copy(inputStream, output.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch(NullPointerException npe) {
        System.out.println("Null Pointer Exception when trying to get runtime agent jar. Since it was not found, aborting.");
        npe.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    //NOTE: This is as far as the code ever gets - remainder of method kept to show intention

    System.out.println("startRuntime: now creating runtime class loader");
    //Handle classloaders.
    ClassLoader extClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent();
    URL[] runtimejarurl = {output.toURI().toURL()};
    ClassLoader runtimeClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(runtimejarurl, null);

    System.out.println("startRuntime: now replacing class loader parent field");
    //Replaces the native bootstrap class loader with ours
    Field f = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("parent");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(extClassLoader, runtimeClassLoader);
    f.setAccessible(false);

    System.out.println("startRuntime: now running Langagent Application main");
    //Have the system class loader load our runtime agent class.
    Class<?> runtimeClass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("com.spnlangagent.langagent.LangagentApplication");
    //Run the main method of the runtime agent
    runtimeClass.getDeclaredMethod("main", String.class).invoke(null, agentArgs);
}
```

The Null Pointer Exception is being caught, meaning that the resource could not be found. I assume this is because the agent assumes it's looking in its own target directory and is not considering (or cannot access) the target directory for the runtime.

I am using Maven, so there is a src and a target directory for the agent, and a src and a target directory for the runtime. My goal is to have the Agent class in the agent module call the `main()` method of the LangagentApplication class located in the .jar in the runtime's target directory, which requires that Maven be able to build the runtime first and then allow the agent to add the runtime to its class path.

My question(s) are as follows: 
How should I configure my maven pom.xml files to allow `Agent.java` to locate the .jar, whether via build commands/local dependencies/etc, given that the class path when run does not include the runtime .jar?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot get target/runtime.jar as a class resource. this jar has been added in the classpath, hence the content of the jar will be available, not the jar itself. if you want the jar to the readable (for some reason) as a resource then target/runtime.jar has to be bundled in agent.jar. I do not think you want that. Are both the jars avaiable in the classpath? If yes, why not just directly call LangagentApplication without reflection. If not then use UrlClassloader without any copying. Clarify your intent.

Comment: What I want to do is execute the main method of LangagentApplication (in the runtime jar) from a method in the agent jar.

Comment: what you have not explained is whether the two jars are in the classpath or not? How have you placed the two jars while executing agent class.

Comment: I am running the agent as follows:

`java -javaagent:/Users/andrewfan/Desktop/Spn-LangAgent/agent/target/Spn-LangAgent-Agent-0.0.jar -jar <application to inject agent into>`

I'm currently not directly setting -cp for either the agent or the runtime.
The placement of the jar files relative to the project directory is exactly as described in my question.

Comment: @gagansingh I did some testing and no, the runtime jar is not in the class path at all - only the agent and the target jar to run the agent on are in the class path.